# WebSphere Portal v.5.1 and AJP?

Tags: java, apache, websphere, ajp

is there a way to configure WebSphere Portal to accept AJP connections? 
E.g. Tomcat/JBoss and Oracle have a specific AJP port. I can't find it in WebSphere, and I'm getting tired of Googlin' around IBM pages.

Thank you in forward...
Balint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Configuring an AJP connector](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/wasce/V1.0/Tasks/Tomcat/Ajp.html)