# how to configure AJP in websphere application sever

Tags: liferay, websphere, ajp

I have deployed liferay 6.1 on WebSphere 8.5 application server which is running on http://localhost:9080,now i want to configure WebSphere to listen AJP request coming from Apache/IHS web server.
Could anyone please provide the steps how to setup AJP configuration at WebSphere end?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Akash

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed 2 things in one question.

For Websphere configuration with AJP, please note below link
[WebSphere Portal v.5.1 and AJP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243071/websphere-portal-v-5-1-and-ajp)

Also, regarding liferay communicating request to AJP, it is not possible as per below.
http://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/37489875

Answer (score 0):

WAS has an IBM HTTP Server. IBM HTTP Server can talk to WAS with the help of IBM WAS plugin. This is preferred and supported configuration.

Take a look at these components in the distribution of WAS.